# Wordpress: Can I edit table fields while media uploading?

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, media, attachment

Is there a way to edit values added into database when I hook to media uploading ( I use `add_attachment` hook ) ?
Basically, what I want to do is:

- hook to media upload
- edit/update a field's value (post_status) from wp_posts table based on $attachment_id
- return

Function would like this:

```
add_filter('add_attachment', 'handle_upload' );

function handle_upload($attachment_id){

//get attachment ID from database: how? I believe that at this point the database is not populated with the new post (media)

// update the post_status field from wp_posts table with some value

//return
}
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What information are you trying to gather? Or what are you trying to update?

Comment: Hi, I'm working on a plugin which doesn't display the image immediately after upload, but after moderation. So, what I need to do is to: 

- hook to an media upload event ( example: add_attachment please point me to another one if this is not the right one ) 

- change the status of the post to "auto_draft"

Comment: Ah so when an item is uploaded, and added to the media library, you want a moderation flag set. You're in the right spot. Let me dig a bit and see if I can find more info for you.

Comment: Awsome! Thanks! I used "wp_update_post" but I think that I try to edit the flag too soon (before it lands on the database)

Comment: I managed to do it. I will post the result! Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. 
The solution is to use `wp_update_post`:

```
function update_db_field($attachment_ID){

    $attachment_details = get_post( $attachment_ID );

    wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $attachment_details->ID ,
            'post_type' => "attachment"
        )
    );
```

}

```
add_action("add_attachment", 'update_db_field');
```

I hope it helps someone else!